# Reading file properties while using readdir() to get the files

Tags: php, file, html-table, directory

I am trying to print file properties into a table while getting the files with `readdir()` but I am receiving an error:

> "Warning: fileperms() [function.fileperms]: stat failed for 0.54322000 1352164273tunes.txt in C:\Users\Desktop\xampp\tybai5131displayBackups.php on line 24"

The file name is so long because I am naming it using `microtime()`

I get the same error for every function, not just `fileperms()`

Here is the PHP code I am using:

```
<table>
<tr><th>File Name</th><th>Owner ID</th><th>Permissions</th><th>File Size</th></tr>
        <?php

            //declare backup directory as a variable
            $dirBackup = "backups/";

            //check if backup directory exists 
            if(!is_dir($dirBackup)) {

                //display error message if backup directory does not exist
                print("You do not have a backup directory yet.");

            } else {

                //else open the directory for reading
                $dirOpenedBackup = opendir($dirBackup);

                while($backupFile = readdir($dirOpenedBackup)){
                    if($backupFile !== '.' && $backupFile !== '..'){
                        print("<tr><td><a href='backups/".$backupFile."'>" .$backupFile. "</a></td><td>".fileowner($backupFile)."</td><td>".fileperms($backupFile)."</td><td>".filesize($backupFile)."</td></tr>");
                    }
                }
            }//close !is_dir 


        ?>
</table>
```

Any ideas of what I can do to get this to work properly?

Comment: Is it only the `fileperms()` that is returning you error or `fileowner()` and `filesize()` too

Answer (score 0):

Next to the physical existance of a file, there can be different other things that can prevent you from accessing the file under a specific user.

You need to verify if you can access the file and the directory the file is located with the user that is used by your PHP script to perform these calls (that depends on your server and PHP configuration). So first find out which is the username.